# How to run an script when user is disconnected from ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, logout

I have a ssh server and i want to execute an specific script each time any user logs in and logs out.

For those who logs in i put my commands at the end of `.bashrc` but for those who logs out i was doing the same but with `.bash_logout`, the problem is that if the user close the terminal instead write exit this file is not executed.

There is some place (maybe related to ssh) where put scripts for execute them in the moment a user is disconnected from ssh?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) or can use `trap` on `SIGHUP`. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463105/probe-ssh-connection-and-detect-ssh-disconnect-or-logout) is a detailed explanation of how to use pam for ssh session management.

Relevant parts from the above [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463105/probe-ssh-connection-and-detect-ssh-disconnect-or-logout):

Add the following in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

```
session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh
```

Create `pam_session.sh` and add the script to detect the ssh disconnection (since `pam_session.sh` will be called during login and logout).

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then
  #DO SOMETHING
fi
```

Comment: is not working, i write in the pam session in the "DO SOMETHING"  `echo "test" >> /tmp/test.txt` but whenever i disconnect it doesn't do anyhting

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez Try a different path. On some systems, `/tmp` is automatically and transparently isolated from other users' `/tmp` by Systemd.

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez make sure you give execute permission to `/etc/pam_session.sh` with `chmod +x /etc/pam_session.sh`